# How to use version control with COMSOL Application builder?

Tags: java, git, comsol

I have built multiple apps using the [COMSOL Application Builder](https://www.comsol.com/release/5.1/application-builder), but have so far not had a good way of keeping track of my code changes.

Is it possible to use GIT or another version control system with the COMSOL Application Builder, and if so, how?

COMSOL Version 5.4